# .Net WebSockets in windows Services

Tags: c#, wcf, websocket, windows-services

I am trying to use web sockets to allow two Windows services on different machines to pass data back and forth. Almost all the examples or information I have found are about using web sockets for Client/Server Side communication. I am having trouble figuring out how to set this up. I have considered using WebSocketHost as apart of Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets, but then I am unsure how to bind it to a local port and not a URL.

Does any one have any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use web sockets to allow two Windows services on different machines to pass data back and forth.

You can open sockets on both machines using WebSockets as you found. The examples mention clients and servers because this is the typical usage, however the API really doesn't care. As long as each side has a listener and a sender they can communicate.

However I would like to mention that this isn't as simple as it sounds because both machines aren't always available. Sometimes one or the other is busy or the network is blocked or something else is going on, or the listener is too busy to respond right away, so you're going to end up needing some sort of queuing on both sides.

If you're doing a process based operation where one side tells the other "I want X" and it's a big operation like producing a document, I've found it much more resilient to build a queue in a database and toss the request in there, then wait for the other side to update the record to say it's done.

If they're smaller, faster requests, MSMQ would be more appropriate if you have it available.

However back to your original question, if you want to use it, any of the client-server examples should work just fine. The API doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalR Self-Host you really don't want to create your own WebSockets framework since this this will take a long time. 
Here is a link on how to start a OWIN server in Windows services.
[Hosting WebAPI using OWIN in a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634333/hosting-webapi-using-owin-in-a-windows-service)
And how to set signalR in self host 
[Tutorial: SignalR Self-Host](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with Memory Mapped Files.

[Inter-Process Communication with Memory-Mapped Files](https://coders-corner.net/2013/03/22/inter-process-communication-with-memory-mapped-files-part-01-transfer-a-data-structure-and-an-object/)

Comment: I don't believe memory mapped files work across the network, since there's no shared memory. The OP specified "on different machines"