# How to use Android device to connect webapi by asp net owin

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, owin, restful-architecture

i recently execute project about owin server (webapi) and android , and i meet some problems to solve, the problems are below statement:

1. webapi that i wrote already OK, tested by browser and fiddler
2. execute webapi on IIS 8 worked fine and android device can get data by restful api
3. execute webapi on owin server now is OK, but when android connect to server by restful 
   that outcome is fail, i am sure message that says"connect server error".

So, the third is key point of problem, can someone help me about my question, tks.

Comment: i found the answer below url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634333/hosting-webapi-using-owin-in-a-windows-service?rq=1