# SignalR works only on localhost

Tags: signalr, owin, self-hosting

In my SignalR Client I have the following javaScript libraries:

```
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="http://localhost:8081/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

In the Javascript I go:

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8081/signalr;
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
var push = $.connection.exosChangeNotifier;
...
$.connection.hub.start().done();
```

The connection works well with localhost.
When I run my SignalR hub on a VM or on another computer and replace localhost with the ip-address or the computer name, I get a

```
http://[servername]:8081/signalr/hubs Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined.
```

I opened up the port 8081 on the firewall on my computer as outgoing rule and as ingoing rule on the remote computer or the VM. With Sysinternal psping I verified that the port is reachable:

```
psping.exe [servername]:8081 -h
```

With a [Powershell Script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7a3304c7-b564-4acc-ab28-2648a20f4bce/telnet-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) I was able to double check the computer is reachable and the port is open.

On the self-hosted SignalR Startup I have CORS enabled:

```
map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you using port 8081 on the server, too?

Comment: Yes. 8081 is used on the Server and Client.Otherwise it would not work when I use it locally.

Comment: it seems that you just have to figure out the correct url which is something that no one on the outside can help you with ...

Comment: I found the solution in [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634333/hosting-webapi-using-owin-in-a-windows-service). The server has to start as http://*:8081 to respond to internal and external requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634333/hosting-webapi-using-owin-in-a-windows-service). The server has to start as http://*:8081 to respond to internal and external requests. Before it was set to only listen to localhost.